# Compare Models before and after submission

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having view which accepts Model

```
@model MyModel
```

Now what I want to do is serialize this model using Jquery and store  it in one global variable.

Now at the time of Submission of form I want to again serialize this model. This models value might have changed . I want this latest serialized model to be compared with old model which was stored in variable. Is there any way to compare these models in single line and depending on that submit form.

Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var oldModel=$('form').serialize();

$('form').submit(function(){
   var newModel=$('form').serialize();
    if(oldModel==newModel)//How can i achieve this?
     e.preventDefault();
});
})
```

Comment: .serialize() generates URL-encoded string, are you having problem  comparing two strings?

Comment: No actually I am not having any issue in comparing string, but properties in my model are numerous

Answer (score 0):

No, none that I'm aware of. You'll have to write a separate function which compares each and every field with the value before submission.